# ERROR:root:Expecting value: line 1 column 55737224 (char 55737223) in json python

Tags: python

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:root:Expecting value: line 1 column 55737224 (char 55737223) how to resolve?

```
try:
        logging.info(f'Try de la función  de paginacion :{today}')
        if os.path.exists("./data/ConsultaAC.json"):
            with open(f'./data/ConsultaAC.json','r') as file:
                        data = json.load(file)
                        print(data)
                       
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
```

Comment: Look at the end of that file and see what's wrong with it. It's most likely a comma at the end of a list (or dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to fix your JSON.  There's a problem in the JSON file about 55MB in.  You can see the region around the problem this way:

```
f = open('data/ConsultaAC.json'.read()
print(f[55737180:55737240])
```